# Fluid IF in Fluid LInk Tag additionalAttributes

Tags: html, typo3, fluid

I want to incorporate a FLUID if in a FLUID link viewhelpers additionalAttributes parameter. But I dont know how to set it correctly.

My try, which renderd an error message:

```
<f:link.page
    pageUid="{layer.link}"
    class="ms-layer ms-button"
    additionalAttributes="{
        data-offset-x:'{layer.offsetX}',
        {f:if(condition: \"{layer.effect} != ''\", then: \"data-effect:'{layer.effect}'\")}
    }">{layer.content}</f:link.page>
```

I am just not sure how to escape all the properties and entries correctly. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

Might be you try to achieve "data-effect" attribute created only if '{layer.effect}' has value, either you can set "data-effect" default or you have to declare variable using [vhs](https://viewhelpers.fluidtypo3.org/fluidtypo3/vhs/5.0.1/Variable/Set.html) viewhelper

```
<f:link.page
    pageUid="{layer.link}"
    class="ms-layer ms-button"
    additionalAttributes="{data-offset-x:'{layer.offsetX}',data-effect:'{f:if(condition: \'{layer.effect}\', then: \'something\', else: \'{layer.effect}\')}'}" >{layer.content}</f:link.page>
```

[more about fluid page link](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/main/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Link/Page.html)

Edited: Now possible to declare variable using fluid [click here](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/main/en-us/typo3fluid/fluid/latest/Variable.html)

Answer (score -1):

I find this also very confusing.

You can try to first set a variable:

```
<v:variable.set name="myvar" value="{f:if(condition: layer.effect != '', then: 'data-effect:'{layer.effect})}" />
```

and then use this new `{myvar}` in the additionalAttributes. Or maybe even better build the hole additionalAttributes in a variable and then use it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Finally I ended up with build a single variable as you suggested, but not in Fluid but in the Controller PHP class.
I find Fluid very confusing, and not very readable, so I chose to use PHP for that.

Comment: In many cases PHP is a lot more readable, I agree. However, it should really not be part of the controller logic. How about using a ViewHelper? Also, on a side note (might not be a solution to your question, but maybe a solution to your problem): wouldn't it be okay to render an empty data attribute and leave the logic to the JS?